# A method of getting a Linux JDK tarball with Freetype-like font rendering

Tags: java, linux, swing, fonts, rendering

I would like to know a method of making a self-contained (tarball) Linux JDK/JRE with a high font rendering quality similar to that provided by the [Freetype project](http://freetype.org). So far, after:

-- trying out different versions of JDK available for Ubuntu:

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~14.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

[image]

(the shape of the # character might be some unrelated font problem, I have no idea)

-- trying out a number of different fonts and sizes, but it seemed orthogonal;

-- switching a number of switches like LCD rendering and antialiasing:

[image]

-- following the recipes like "apply some patched packages and scripts from different repos to your Ubuntu derivative", (this did not work for me, at least not some time ago, worked on the distro level and offered a fixed version of the jdk)

-- resigning from Swing and trying to make a GUI in JavaFX instead,

I started to believe that I won't get a font rendering comparable to Freetype. Then I stumbled into Android Studio, which was all of three Java and Linux and a Freetype-like font rendering:

[image]

And it turned out it all boils down to the JRE it uses:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_76-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.76-b03, mixed mode)
```

I tried to compile OpenJDK from sources with FreeType enabled:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libasound2-dev libasound2-dev libX11-dev libxext-dev libxrender-dev libxtst-dev libxt-dev
mkdir freetype && ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 freetype/include && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ freetype/lib
sudo apt-get install ccache
cd YourOpenJDK
bash ./configure --with-freetype=../freetype --with-cups=/usr/include/cups --with-x=/usr/include/X11/extensions --with-jvm-variants=server --with-target-bits=64 --with-debug-level=release

    checking if we can compile and link with freetype... yes`
    checking if we should bundle freetype... yes`

make all
```

but it does not work - font rendering is still like on the two first images.

The differences become smaller for well-hinted fonts:

[image]

[image]

but the renderer which requires proper hints still does a bad job - all of the fonts in the 4th image have flaws:

1. Jaggy antialiasing with uneven contrast.
2. Colorful fringe.
3. Median and ascent lines badly aligned with pixels.
4. Curves of a wavy width.
5. A tendency to single-pixel-width "strings" which distort shape.
6. Misshaped certain details. See e.g. the median line serifs in the bottom line font, they are fuzzy and lack shape, and this is a 27px font.

And thus the questions:

**1. Is there a method of preparing a portable tarball (not system-wide modifications) of any recent version of JDK/JRE, which has a font rendering quality similar to that seen in the third/5th image?**

**2. If the newest early access OpenJDK:**

```
java version "1.8.0_122-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_122-ea-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.122-b04, mixed mode)
```

**has the "traditional Linux Java" font rendering again, can it be that the method used in the case of the third image is a feature later abandoned?**

Comment: Ok what that mean?  `I would like to know a method of making a self-contained (tarball) Linux JDK/JRE with font rendering similar to that of Freetype` If it means that you need a custom font that looks like Freetype then you can find one(.ttf) and easily apply to the css of your JavaFX application and it will work regardless the Java Version. Of course it must support JavaFX first :)  If you want to bundle it inside your JRE i would like to know why? Finally +1 cause it is interesting.

Comment: GOX, Freetype is a project which provides font rendering of an exceptional quality. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns that there is a custom jdk JetBrain OpenJDK, which has a greatly improved font rendering.